# Modules, endomorphism and ideals

Tags: ring-theory, modules

I was solving tasks in a book and there are two tasks where I have no idea how to solve them:

1) Let $R$ be commutative ring, $f: M\rightarrow N$ - isomorphism of $R$-modules. Prove isomorphism of modules $\operatorname{End}_R(M)$ and $\operatorname{End}_R(N)$.

@Crostul proposed to observe this map $F: \phi \mapsto f^{-1}\circ\phi\circ f$. It's easily to check that this is bijection. We need to show that:

a) $F(\phi + \psi) = F(\phi) + F(\psi)$

$F(\phi + \psi)(x) = f^{-1}\circ(\phi + \psi)\circ f(x) = f^{-1}\circ(\phi(f(x)) +\psi(f(x))) \\= f^{-1}\circ\phi\circ f(x) + f^{-1}\circ\psi\circ f(x)$.

All equations are correct because $f$ - isomorphism of modules and $\phi$ - 
homomorphism (endomorphism) between modules

b)$F(a\phi) = aF(\phi)$ where $a\in R$. It's also obvious.

But I did not understood why $R$ must be commutative? Can you show me situation where it's necessary?

Comment: 1) The isomorphism between the two endomorphism rings is $a \mapsto f^{-1} \circ a \circ f$.

Comment: @Crostul It's obvious that $a +b \mapsto f^{-1}\circ a\circ f +  f^{-1}\circ b\circ f$ and $\alpha a\mapsto \alpha ( f^{-1}\circ a\circ f)$. Why it's important that the ring is commutative?

Comment: if the ring is not commutative, then $\mathrm{End}_R(M)$ might not have a $R$-module structure.

Comment: By $R\setminus I_1$ surely you mean the quotient ring? The reason I ask is that it is more standard to write $R/I_1$, because $R\setminus I_1$ suggests the difference of sets, which doesn't have any apparent ring structure.

Comment: Also, it would be better not to dump tasks without your progress, and definitely not two no-progress tasks in the same post.  Before anyone answers, you might want to narrow the question to just one of the two and work improving it.